# OpenMDAO: How to set a constraint bound as the output of another component?

Tags: openmdao

I want to minimize the output of one component while ensuring that it is larger than the output of a second component.

The add_constraint expects an "Iterable of numeric values, or a scalar numeric value" when I feed it a string with the name of the output.

When given `prob['name']` the error is "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

This has got to be something simple and documented, but I haven't found it yet.

```
import openmdao.api as om

prob=om.Problem()
independant = prob.model.add_subsystem('independant', om.IndepVarComp())
independant.add_output('x', val = 3.0)

prob.model.add_subsystem('steep_line', om.ExecComp('f = x'))
prob.model.add_subsystem('shallow_line', om.ExecComp('g = 0.5*x + 1.0'))

prob.model.connect('independant.x', ['steep_line.x', 'shallow_line.x'])

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('independant.x', lower=0.0, upper=3.0)

#Change which of the next two lines is commented out to see both errors I
#have encountered.
prob.model.add_constraint('steep_line.f', lower='shallow_line.g')
#prob.model.add_constraint('steep_line.f', lower=prob['shallow_line.g'])

prob.model.add_objective('steep_line.f')

prob.setup()
prob.run_driver()

print('x:', prob['independant.x'])
```

The desired result is an optimization that arrives at independant.x = 2.0

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a non-constant lower, upper, or, equals bound. To make this work, you need to add (another) ExecComp, and then subtract the two values from eachother. Then you can set the resulting output of this new comp to have a lower bound of 0

```
import openmdao.api as om

prob=om.Problem()
independant = prob.model.add_subsystem('independant', om.IndepVarComp())
independant.add_output('x', val = 3.0)

prob.model.add_subsystem('steep_line', om.ExecComp('f = x'))
prob.model.add_subsystem('shallow_line', om.ExecComp('f = 0.5*x + 1.0'))

prob.model.add_subsystem('constraint', 
                         om.ExecComp('g = f_computed - lower'))

prob.model.connect('independant.x', ['steep_line.x', 'shallow_line.x'])
prob.model.connect('shallow_line.f', 'constraint.lower')
prob.model.connect('steep_line.f', 'constraint.f_computed')

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('independant.x', lower=0.0, upper=3.0)

prob.model.add_constraint('constraint.g', lower=0)

prob.model.add_objective('steep_line.f')

prob.setup()
prob.run_driver()

print('x:', prob['independant.x'])
```

Comment: Thank you for that solution, it wasn't occurring to me. A small correction to the solution for future users referring to this post: ```prob.model.add_subsystem('constraint', om.ExecComp('g = lower-f_computed'))``` should be ```prob.model.add_subsystem('constraint', om.ExecComp('g = f_computed - lower'))``` to receive the desired result.